# Facing challenge with selenium webdriver on Win 10 system

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

[image]

I am trying to automate login on a website using selenium. (Windows 10 64 bit os)

Using the below code I am able to open a link,
But once webpage loads the get cmd does not release my python interpreter
next cmd:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('gb_g').click()
```

does not run.

I tried to open google.com but the issue is same, I tried different browser it works but my project URL only works with internet explorer.

I have tried with both 64 & 32-bit driver version of internet explorer

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

link = 'https://www.google.com/'
browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='S:\work\Automation\Elog\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.get(link)
browser.find_element_by_class_name('gb_g').click()
```

Comment: Can you please inform us why you are trying to run IEDriverServer with FireFox? I suggest you to try to run it with Internet Explorer. Also try to check and make sure that you are using the latest version of IEDriverServer.

Comment: Before asking the question I tried to use firefox browser to check, so while pasting here I fail edit code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a few things:

- If your use case is to use [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) you need to use *IEDriverServer.exe* through `selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver.WebDriver()` *Class* as follows:

  ```
  webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'S:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe')
  ```

---

To `click()` on the element with text as **Gmail** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'S:\work\Automation\Elog\IEDriverServer.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Gmail"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'S:\work\Automation\Elog\IEDriverServer.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.google.com/")       
  WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.gb_g[href*='com/mail/?tab']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'S:\work\Automation\Elog\IEDriverServer.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Gmail']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update (from @rahuldesai's comment)

With the above mentioned configurations and using the **32 bit** **`IEDriverServer`** binary some how the issue gets fixed.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, the problem is with get() command it freezes the interpreter it opens requested webpage but does not release interpreter so than next command can execute

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _does not release interpreter_?

Comment: get() cmd keeps running even after loading the webpage, I have added an image for reference

Comment: Check my answer, you need to induce _WebDriverWait_ for `document.ready` state as **complete** first for `get()` to be completed.

Comment: @rahul desai -- Run this python code above in PyCharm or execute it from the command line.  Here is a link to download PyCharm.  Jupyter is cool and all but for this try PyCharm.

Comment: @rahuldesai Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I tried with Pycharm and Spyder both IDE but it did not help. Also reinstalled selenium still same problem

Comment: Tried using 32-bit Ie driver shomhow resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution for the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @rahuldesai I have update the answer with your comments which solves the issue.